# Exoplayer : Audio is working but not video shows white screen?

Tags: android, exoplayer

**This is my Exoplayer Code :** 
I am using this code in my Fragment class. I am streaming the video from network, getting the video url and passing a uri to the initializePlayer(uri) method.

```
        private void initializePlayer(Uri mediaUri)    {
        if (mExoPlayer == null) {
            TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);
            TrackSelector trackSelector =
                new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

            mExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), 
            trackSelector);
            mSimpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(mExoPlayer);

            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new 
            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("Baking");
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new 
            DefaultExtractorsFactory();

            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, 
            dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory,
                null, null);

            mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

         }
      }
```

Comment: Did you check with real device or emulator?

Comment: I checked on the Emulator and on my device also, in my device it just loads the **SimpleExoPlayerView** and does not seek or play video. Don't know what do ?

Comment: Weere you able to solve this